# Does React's type declarations e.g. React.HTMLAttribute<HTMLButtonElement> support the usage of custom data attributes out of the box?

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript, custom-data-attribute

I'm trying to create an object that can be spread into a React Component and this object has to include an [HTML Custom Data Attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*).

```
import { HTMLAttributes } from 'react'

interface FooProps extends HTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement> {
  fooProp: string
  //'data-testid': string // do HTML Custom Attributes not come out of the box?
}

const fooObj: FooProps = {
  fooProp: 'yay',
  'data-testid': 'nay' // Object literal may only specify known properties, and ''data-testid'' does not exist in type 'Foo'.(2353)
}

const Foo = () => <button {...fooObj}></button>
```

In the [example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true&noErrorTruncation=true#code/FASwtgDg9gTgLgAgN4IBIBUCyAZAgnOGEAIwFc4BTAZwQF8EAzGKMBAchgoEMBjON4KAB2lGA14UEAMShQACswg0KAD0pCAJjQw58hEuWoAeHdgBC5OFCEBRADYUwFEQD5kwBI1kKoEAFwIVPpCAOYeCAD0EWwaXHBcALSUQSAabAFBRKGREQgaUGhY2AgAwqRBLAh6RGTJCEJQiDwsklDkCFAMCHAAFpLEUCoA-MC0gs1CQV5QAPLEAFYBMvKKNAC87p4M3ooBbACeXPtsADThMXGJyXCp6exCR2w5CHPzFHwIdiCiXHYIYEcOkI7PtAhB3iAGKCANYNADuQgQEEUFHgIGoJwQXE07Au8SS1BuaSe+Wo9UaCFUICmIERcH24PYyzYADoABQAJgAzABWLkASlG42sU2WCA2bP54rcRlqVkRSBZSu2swWtBcRgicusLiAA) above, I can't seem to type my object to allow for custom data attributes without having to explicitly list them out. How do I type the object to allow for custom data attributes without explicit declarations?

Comment: Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77701532/edit) the question to include a [mre]? I can't reproduce: https://tsplay.dev/WJBx5W

Comment: Appreciate it man, I just updated my question with a repro example

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77701532/does-reacts-type-declarations-e-g-react-htmlattributehtmlbuttonelement-suppo?noredirect=1#comment136987430_77701532) @geoyws Please add the [mre] to the content of the question — links (e.g. to the TS playground) are potentially very helpful supportive material, but aren't substitutes for question content.

Comment: Re: the playground link you posted: You've created a type and shown a data structure which can't be assigned to that type… but what's the issue? It seems like you might be making some assumptions about the types exported by [`@types/react`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/react), but the actual problem that you're trying to solve by creating a custom type is still not clear. Please demonstrate the problem with a [mre] that clarifies your expectations and what about them is not being met.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although [custom data attributes `data-*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) are recognized by the TypeScript compiler when using JSX syntax — e.g. this compiles without error…

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true&noErrorTruncation=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBDAnmApnA3nASighgYxgFEAbFEFAO3gF84AzKCEOAIij0NYG4AoX+gFdKhYBEpwiAD1zgyAYWaRKVGAAoAlAC5snYmQrUMvAJAcYgqBLWmTAHgBGgmDHG2TAE1wxcAWnoQEAC8rA64UKzu4vIkwPgA1kHoaigAbhpwQQB8cPjiAM4QZAB0JBAA5impxfiWHNQAKuHlKDDFXj75rcUBEBo0tlnuMXHxtnYA9E4u4kMmGnwDQA)

```ts
import type { ReactElement } from "react";

function ExampleComponent(): ReactElement {
  return (
    <button
      data-foo="bar"
      onClick={(ev) => console.log(ev.currentTarget.dataset.foo)}
    >
      Click
    </button>
  );
}
```

…React does not [provide](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/bf547ec1bd81d58c85eb0ea562524798410bfaf5/types/react/index.d.ts) element attribute type aliases/interfaces which include them.

In order to allow for custom data attributes in your own types, you can either include them explicitly at each definition…

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true&noErrorTruncation=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBDAnmApnA3nAQgVxjCAOwAkAVAWQBkBBfKYAIzxQGcAaOAJRQEMBjGAFEANihApC8AL5wAZlAgg4AIii8BygNwAobUlRwAIjxg9aMekxis4AXi4o+0ACYAeAAbOTPALQASdBYLYEIAcyl3DiD6MIA+HW0AekS4QQAPMGFgPmAYYUQ4EOsoFkd4GAALNBDnFDSUZwRkFAAubSdCILgrAkJzEpbsPF6yKn7GZhZXUcpcfCIRMQkYWLgAMiNvcasbe3QklLgj45PTs-OLy6u4AD07+4fHm+0ASGUvUx9ZCAhlQeUGDwoMo2K8iABhLJ8ADWgwAFCgAG4ASjsqw6LAgogAdMIIKEEYjsXwcFA1JJSEDQigYNiPjxSrTvhBkaCpAlZDhCAJgERUmkeOBRODFJBCMs4cjBtx+EJROJJBhXmoYKTCHBXD0+ehsbqtX06CwpLFIdloa5Evr4topNogA)

```ts
import type { ButtonHTMLAttributes, ReactElement } from "react";

type DataAttributes = Record<`data-${string}`, string>;

// Explicitly intersect the indexed type:
const buttonAttrs: ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement> & DataAttributes = {
//                                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  "data-foo": "bar",
  onClick: (ev) => console.log(ev.currentTarget.dataset.foo),
};

function ExampleComponent(): ReactElement {
  return <button {...buttonAttrs}>Click</button>;
}
```

…or — you can approach it in a much more [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) way by using the pattern of [module augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation):

Create a type declaration file in your project at a path that is [included in your program's compilation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#include) (e.g. `src/types/react_data_attributes.d.ts`):

```ts
import type {} from "react";

declare module "react" {
  interface HTMLAttributes<T> {
    [name: `data-${string}`]: string;
  }
}
```

> Ref: [microsoft/TypeScript#36812 — Add `import type "mod"`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36812)

Then, at each usage site, the explicit intersection will no longer be needed:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true&noErrorTruncation=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBDAnmApnA3nAQgVxjCAOwAkAVAWQBkBBfKYAIzxQGcAaOAJRQEMBjGAFEANihApC8AL5wAZlAgg4AIii8BygNwAobQBMUfYTzVwQEPTlEq1-GMozaAkMEkoos-mjJVaMekwwrAA8pAB8jk5OANqEPOIAXHAABno8MDwAtAAk6Cz+rgDmUskAukn59ISFOk5S2vXaAPRNcAByEADuHETCiAgAFmgMPCzDeASEcOkFgawIyGg8hIQQGTDARHDALHCEKCgGegnafET5cIGTflAsSbj4RD40dIzMLMHPD5MiYhIwEQAvJFlGkMplZBAIMoksoRlBlGxnEQAMLCYB8ADWSQAFCgAG4ASjggIiZ0ILAgogAdMIIIU8fjqXwcFA1JJSCZCigYNSwaMedTIRBCUipDptLIcIQBJspoIAB7xMCiFGKSD7SQ4wlJbh2X7iSSRNQwVlTYJXLboak2y2EG4sKRhNEYzHBJp2sI6epAA)

```ts
import type { ButtonHTMLAttributes, ReactElement } from "react";

// Now, only the base button attributes type annotation is needed:
const buttonAttrs: ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement> = {
  "data-foo": "bar",
  onClick: (ev) => console.log(ev.currentTarget.dataset.foo),
};

function ExampleComponent(): ReactElement {
  return <button {...buttonAttrs}>Click</button>;
}
```

---

A note regarding `HTMLElement` subtypes:

Each subtype (e.g. `<button>`, `<a>`, etc.) might have specialized attributes in addition what's offered in the base `HTMLAttributes`, so you'll need to type your element attributes accordingly for the compiler to recognize those specific attributes. Here's an example showing some of the specialized attributes for the elements above:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true&noErrorTruncation=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBDAnmApnA3gKAJAEEB2AxgBbQASAKgLIAyuMMUwARgK4woDOANDgELsYEfJVr1GLdl17ZRdBkzYcemAL5wAZlAgg4AIigoAhoRh6A3JkxJUcAQ2EBlVIWAbghcYqmc4AXjgAUQAPQgAbVgATFAAeTDgEgHpEgD0AfhwAaxRECA07QWE5L0llGLl7IXxAsJQQFHwYAD4ZbNz84oVSrnLqGkrhGrqG5swmy2tkNAISaGcUV3dPLqUufyDQiOi4hLhk9KycvLgZ0ihOiVXOXrEiM6H6xpbD9rgL7zLiu+gHkaaxiaEYSceBKKpeTgABgAXG8+iUrjd+oVqrVHs11lhsJFgJwjMxapFYYxWCheKpAcDQSiIQBGWEDETwlY+JGM35PTE4HF4gkoIkIKCk8mU-AguBGb5QCEwuFiFmfeFSjkYgJY4iGDSwvTEBhgTjQ5IgkyZCAANxQUA0YQgAHcAHRAkCJPQiqxAsXwSWzaUKTj0k5S97da5fH0qppc7AalBa-S6mD6w2JY2EU0Wq02h1Ol1uoA)

```ts
import type {
  AnchorHTMLAttributes,
  ButtonHTMLAttributes,
  HTMLAttributes,
} from "react";

type ButtonSpecificAttributes = Exclude<
  /* ^? type ButtonSpecificAttributes =
    | "disabled"
    | "form"
    | "formAction"
    | "formEncType"
    | "formMethod"
    | "formNoValidate"
    | "formTarget"
    | "name"
    | "type"
    | "value"
  */
  keyof ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>,
  keyof HTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>
>;

type AnchorSpecificAttributes = Exclude<
  /* ^? type AnchorSpecificAttributes =
    | "download"
    | "href"
    | "hrefLang"
    | "media"
    | "ping"
    | "referrerPolicy"
    | "target"
    | "type"
  */
  keyof AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>,
  keyof HTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>
>;

const buttonAttrs0: HTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement> = {
  disabled: true, /* Error
  ~~~~~~~~
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'disabled' does not exist in type 'HTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>'.(2353) */
};

const buttonAttrs1: ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement> = {
  disabled: true, // Ok
};

const anchorAttrs0: HTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement> = {
  href: "https://stackoverflow.com/", /* Error
  ~~~~
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'href' does not exist in type 'HTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>'.(2353) */
};

const anchorAttrs1: AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement> = {
  href: "https://stackoverflow.com/", // Ok
};
```